# basic ORMLite database questions

Tags: java, h2, ormlite

I have two questions about the examples listed on the [ORMLIte website](http://ormlite.com/docs/examples).

- Where do I put the database and how do I import it?
- Which class do I put the DAO and the connection factory in?

Comment: I'm trying to run this http://ormlite.com/docs/example-simple and go through this: http://ormlite.com/docs/getting-started

Comment: Alex, you also asked the user mailing list the same question.  Please consider removing this from stack overflow.  It does not provide enough information about your configuration (android, jdbc?) so that other people can be helpful.  I'll respond on the mailing list.

Comment: please update your question with the additional detail instead of just adding a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where do I put the database and how do I import it.

Do you mean the h2 jar file? As described in the getting started document (1.4 Code Example), you need to add the h2 jar file to the class path. If you are not sure how to set the class path, please investigate that first, because that's a very important concept in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the database Models with the annotations
@DatabaseTable()

and

@DatabaseField()

Like:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="YOUR_TABLE_NAME")
public class SimpleDataModel {
    @DatabaseField(id=true)
    private int idSimpleData;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String NameSomeDataHere;
}
```

You don't have to import it, just create a Helper class with extends to ORMSqliteOpenHelper.

It's pretty well documented, just search a bit at ORMLite site. But an example is:

```
public class dbHelper extends ORMSqliteOpenHelper {
    onCreate() { // I'm letting some code behind, as long as Eclipse do implement methods for you. ;)
        TableUtils.CreateTable(connectionSource, SimpleDataModel.class);
        //This one above is what is going to create your tables.
        //Afterwards you have to use DAO's to access your data, os it's nonsense.
        //So if you're a begginner at android just read the ENTIRE documentarion of ORMLite, and MAYBE you'll understand something ;P        

}
```